# SQL Select Query Highest Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `Game`:

```
  Player     Score
    1         100
    2         250
    2         300
    3         150
    4         700
    5         400
    5         500
    6         800
```

I need a query to return the highest score for each Player:

```
    1 - 100
    2 - 300
    3 - 150
    4 - 700
    5 - 500
    6 - 800
```

So far I have this

```
    SELECT Player, Score FROM Game
```

It returns everything but I just need what I explained above.

Comment: What have you tried?  Is this homework?  It looks like a pretty straightforward use of `max()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a `group by` on player.

```
SELECT Player, max(Score) as maxscore 
FROM Game
group by player
```